Use PhysicalNamingStrategy on underlying DataSources of AbstractRoutingDataSource
i am using spring-boot with hibernate's PhysicalNamingStrategy together with a AbstractRoutingDataSource from spring and MS SQL Server. The goal is to have a dynamic schema switching for different tenants. Since MS SQL does not support schema setting in the jdbc driver, i need a solution to generate SQL scripts where the schema name is part of the table name as prefix, but dynamically depending on the current TenantId which is stored as ThreadLocal in the AbstractRoutingDataSource implementation.
   @Bean
    public CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy myPhysicalNamingStrategy(MyDataSourceRouter dataSourceRouter) {

        return new CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy() {

            @Override
            public Identifier toPhysicalSchemaName(Identifier logicalName, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {

                // read schema here either from jdbcEnvironment datasource of from thread local variable of the dataSourceRouter. 
                return Identifier.toIdentifier(dataSourceRouter.getCurrentSchema());
            }
        };
    }

Sadly the the physical schema name is only initialized once on startup and only for the default DataSource of AbstractRoutingDataSource and for not their underlying DataSources.
I also tried to use the described solutions from this spring blog: [https://spring.io/blog/2022/07/31/how-to-integrate-hibernates-multitenant-feature-with-spring-data-jpa-in-a-spring-boot-application].
But since MS SQL does not support "setSchema" on DataSource or Connection objects, none of this approaches is a solution. Therefore MultiTenantConnectionProvider is not a solution for MS SQL.
How can i "teach" PhysicalNamingStragtegy to work together with AbstractRoutingDataSource? It seems like PhysicalNamingStragtegy is only applied to the defaultDataSource of AbstractRoutingDataSource
